# Spring Cloud Messaging Source is not sending messages to Kafka broker

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am following the 'Spring Microservices In Action' book, with some small deviations from the format chosen by the author. Namely, I am using Kotlin and Gradle rather than Java and Maven. Other than that, I am mostly following the code as presented.

In the chapter on Messaging I am running into a problem - I cannot publish a message using the Source class I am autowiring into my SimpleSourceBean.

I know the general setup is OK, as the Kafka topic is created, and on application startup I see the corresponding log messages. I've tried autowiring the source explicitly in the class body as well as in the constructor, but no success in either case

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableBinding(Source::class)
@EnableCircuitBreaker
class OrganizationServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    fun getRestTemplate(): RestTemplate {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val interceptors = restTemplate.interceptors

        interceptors.add(UserContextInterceptor())
        restTemplate.interceptors = interceptors

        return restTemplate
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<OrganizationServiceApplication>(*args)
}
```

This is the SimpleSourceBean implementation:

```
@Component
class SimpleSourceBean {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var source: Source

    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    fun publishOrgChange(action: String, orgId: String) {
        logger.debug("Sending Kafka message $action for Organization $orgId on source ${source}")
        val change = OrganizationChangeModel(
                OrganizationChangeModel::class.java.typeName,
                action,
                orgId,
                UserContext.correlationId!!)

        logger.debug("change message: $change")

        source.output()
                .send(MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(change)
                        .build())

        logger.debug("Sent Kafka message $action for Organization $orgId successfully")
    }
}
```

and this is the Service class that uses the SimpleSourceBean to send the message to Kafka:

```
@Component
class OrganizationService {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var organizationRepository: OrganizationRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var simpleSourceBean: SimpleSourceBean

    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrganizationService::class.java)

    // some omissions for brevity

    @HystrixCommand(
            fallbackMethod = "fallbackUpdate",
            commandKey = "updateOrganizationCommandKey",
            threadPoolKey = "updateOrganizationThreadPool")
    fun updateOrganization(organizationId: String, organization: Organization): Organization {
        val updatedOrg = organizationRepository.save(organization)
        simpleSourceBean.publishOrgChange("UPDATE", organizationId)
        return updatedOrg
    }

    private fun fallbackUpdate(organizationId: String, organization: Organization) =
            Organization(id = "000-000-00", name = "update not saved", contactEmail = "", contactName = "", contactPhone = "")

    @HystrixCommand
    fun saveOrganization(organization: Organization): Organization {
        val orgToSave = organization.copy(id = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        val savedOrg = organizationRepository.save(orgToSave)
        simpleSourceBean.publishOrgChange("SAVE", savedOrg.id)
        return savedOrg
    }
}
```

The log messages

```
organizationservice_1           | 2019-08-23 23:15:33.939 DEBUG 18 --- [ionThreadPool-2] S.O.events.source.SimpleSourceBean       : Sending Kafka message UPDATE for Organization e254f8c-c442-4ebe-a82a-e2fc1d1ff78a on source null
organizationservice_1           | 2019-08-23 23:15:33.940 DEBUG 18 --- [ionThreadPool-2] S.O.events.source.SimpleSourceBean       : change message: OrganizationChangeModel(type=SpringMicroservicesInAction.OrganizationService.events.source.OrganizationChangeModel, action=UPDATE, organizationId=e254f8c-c442-4ebe-a82a-e2fc1d1ff78a, correlationId=c84d288f-bfd6-4217-9026-8a45eab058e1)
organizationservice_1           | 2019-08-23 23:15:33.941 DEBUG 18 --- [ionThreadPool-2] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : preSend on channel 'output', message: GenericMessage [payload=OrganizationChangeModel(type=SpringMicroservicesInAction.OrganizationService.events.source.OrganizationChangeModel, action=UPDATE, organizationId=e254f8c-c442-4ebe-a82a-e2fc1d1ff78a, correlationId=c84d288f-bfd6-4217-9026-8a45eab058e1), headers={id=05799740-f8cf-85f8-54f8-74fce2679909, timestamp=1566602133941}]
organizationservice_1           | 2019-08-23 23:15:33.945 DEBUG 18 --- [ionThreadPool-2] tractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler : org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler@38675bb5 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[224], headers={contentType=application/json, id=64e1e8f1-45f4-b5e6-91d7-c2df28b3d6cc, timestamp=1566602133943}]
organizationservice_1           | 2019-08-23 23:15:33.946 DEBUG 18 --- [ionThreadPool-2] nder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler : org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@763a88a received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[224], headers={contentType=application/json, id=7be5d188-5309-cba9-8297-74431c410152, timestamp=1566602133945}]
```

There are no further messages logged, which includes the final DEBUG log statement of the SimpleSourceBEan

Checking inside the Kafka container if there are any messages on the 'orgChangeTopic' topic, it comes up empty:

```
root@99442804288f:/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin# ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --from-beginning --topic orgChangeTopic --bootstrap-server 0.0.0.0:9092
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

Any pointer to where my problem might lie is greatly appreciated

edit:

adding the application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination:  orgChangeTopic
          content-type: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: "http://kafkaserver:2181"
          brokers: "http://kafkaserver:9092"

// omitting some irrelevant config

logging:
  level:
    org.apache.kafka: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: WARN
    springmicroservicesinaction.organizationservice: DEBUG
```

excerpt of the build.gradle file with relevant dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // kotlin, spring boot, etc
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:2.2.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka:2.2.0.RELEASE")
}
```

Comment: You need to show your application properties as well. Your kafka version is very old; 0.10.x.x doesn't support headers. What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? Modern versions require a Kafka that supports headers (0.11 or preferably later - the current release is 2.3), unless you set the `headerMode` to `none`. That said, I would expect to see an error message if we try to send headers to a version that doesn't support them.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for taking a look. I am using the [spotify/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka/dockerfile) docker image, which seems to explain the older version of Kafka. Like I said, I am mostly just following the book (and have had no experience with Kafka up to this point). I did a little bit of research and will try to upgrade to a more recent version of Zookeeper and Kafka.

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much for your help! I migrated from spotify/kafka to [johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/r/johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper/) and that solved the issue for me. If you write a one liner reply to my question, I'll mark it as the answer. Again, greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show your application properties as well. Your kafka version is very old; 0.10.x.x doesn't support headers. What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? Modern versions require a Kafka that supports headers (0.11 or preferably later - the current release is 2.3), unless you set the `headerMode` to `none`.

That said, I would expect to see an error message if we try to send headers to a version that doesn't support them.

> implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:2.2.0.RELEASE")

Also note that with modern versions, you no longer need

```
zkNodes: "http://kafkaserver:2181"
```

The kafka-clients version used by 2.2.0 supports topic provisioning via the Kafka broker directly and we no longer need to connect to zookeeper.